# Load File In HttpServer C# In Apple Browser

Tags: c#, ios, http, server, httpserver

I Write Http server In C#

In handleGETRequest When Request A File i Wrote :

```
if (p.http_url.Equals("/Test.png"))
{
    Stream fs = File.Open("../../Test.png", FileMode.Open);
    fs.CopyTo(p.outputStream.BaseStream);
    p.outputStream.BaseStream.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

This Work In All Browser In Windows And Android But Not Load In IOS Phone In Safari.I Tested In All Browser In Apple Seven And Apple Six .

Error Message Is :
unable to write data to transport connection http request